# Ambari sync with LDAP using StartTLS

Tags: ldap, synchronization, starttls

I'm facing an issue to sync Ambari with a LDAP server using StartTLS and a self-signed certificate. Ambari server and ldap server are both running on the same machine. I've followed the steps written in [the doc](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.4/bk_security/content/_configure_ambari_to_use_ldap_server.html) but I'm not sure if I'm in the LDAPS configuration case or not.

If I follow the SSL configuration case and import the self-signed certificate into /etc/ambari-server/keys/ldaps-keystore.jks then I get the error bellow from the ambari server when I do ambari-server sync-ldap --all

```
AmbariLdapDataPopulator:736 - Reloading properties ldapSyncEventResourceProvider:460 - Caught exception running LDAP sync. 
org.springframework.ldap.CommunicationException: simple bind failed:    
host.example.net:389; nested exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: host.example.net:389 
[Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake]
    at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:108)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.createContext(AbstractContextSource.java:356)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.doGetContext(AbstractContextSource.java:140)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.getReadOnlyContext(AbstractContextSource.java:159)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:357)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:309)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:642)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.security.ldap.AmbariLdapDataPopulator.getFilteredLdapUsers(AmbariLdapDataPopulator.java:667)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.security.ldap.AmbariLdapDataPopulator.getExternalLdapUserInfo(AmbariLdapDataPopulator.java:644)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.security.ldap.AmbariLdapDataPopulator.synchronizeAllLdapUsers(AmbariLdapDataPopulator.java:212)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariManagementControllerImpl.synchronizeLdapUsersAndGroups(AmbariManagementControllerImpl.java:5177)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.internal.LdapSyncEventResourceProvider.syncLdap(LdapSyncEventResourceProvider.java:490)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.internal.LdapSyncEventResourceProvider.processSyncEvents(LdapSyncEventResourceProvider.java:448)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.internal.LdapSyncEventResourceProvider.access$000(LdapSyncEventResourceProvider.java:65)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.internal.LdapSyncEventResourceProvider$1.run(LdapSyncEventResourceProvider.java:259)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed: host.example.net:389 [Root exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapClient.authenticate(LdapClient.java:219)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2788)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:319)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:192)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:210)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:153)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:83)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
    at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:154)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource.getDirContextInstance(LdapContextSource.java:42)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.createContext(AbstractContextSource.java:344)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:992)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:928)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.Connection.run(Connection.java:860)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    ... 8 more
```

While the ldap server gives me: err=13 nentries=0 text=TLS confidentiality required

```
slapd debug  conn=16624 fd=13 ACCEPT from IP=datanode3:51578 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
slapd debug  conn=16624 op=0 BIND dn="" method=128
slapd debug  conn=16624 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
slapd debug  conn=16624 op=1 SRCH base="dc=example,dc=net" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uidNumber=-1))"
slapd debug  conn=16624 op=1 SRCH attr=uid userPassword uidNumber gidNumber cn homeDirectory loginShell gecos description objectClass
slapd debug  conn=16624 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=13 nentries=0 text=TLS confidentiality required
slapd debug  conn=16624 op=2 UNBIND
slapd debug  conn=16624 fd=13 closed
slapd debug  conn=16625 fd=13 ACCEPT from IP=datanode3:51580 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
slapd debug  conn=16625 op=0 BIND dn="" method=128
slapd debug  conn=16625 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
slapd debug  conn=16625 op=1 SRCH base="dc=example,dc=net" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uidNumber=-1))"
slapd debug  conn=16625 op=1 SRCH attr=uid userPassword uidNumber gidNumber cn homeDirectory loginShell gecos description objectClass
slapd debug  conn=16625 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=13 nentries=0 text=TLS confidentiality required
slapd debug  conn=16625 op=2 UNBIND
slapd debug  conn=16625 fd=13 closed
slapd debug  conn=16626 fd=13 ACCEPT from IP=datanode3:51584 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
slapd debug  conn=16626 op=0 BIND dn="" method=128
slapd debug  conn=16626 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
slapd debug  conn=16626 op=1 SRCH base="dc=example,dc=net" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uidNumber=-1))"
slapd debug  conn=16626 op=1 SRCH attr=uid userPassword uidNumber gidNumber cn homeDirectory loginShell gecos description objectClass
slapd debug  conn=16626 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=13 nentries=0 text=TLS confidentiality required
slapd debug  conn=16626 op=2 UNBIND
slapd debug  conn=16626 fd=13 closed
slapd debug  conn=2419 op=4783 SRCH base="dc=example,dc=net" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=ambari-qa))"
slapd debug  conn=2419 op=4783 SRCH attr=uid uidNumber
slapd debug  conn=2419 op=4783 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=13 nentries=0 text=TLS confidentiality required
slapd debug  conn=2419 op=4784 ABANDON msg=4784
slapd debug  conn=2685 op=4529 SRCH base="dc=example,dc=net" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=ambari-qa))"
slapd debug  conn=2685 op=4529 SRCH attr=uid uidNumber
slapd debug  conn=2685 op=4529 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=13 nentries=0 text=TLS confidentiality required
slapd debug  conn=2685 op=4530 ABANDON msg=4530
slapd debug  conn=2685 op=4531 SRCH base="dc=example,dc=net" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=ambari-qa))"
slapd debug  conn=2685 op=4531 SRCH attr=uid uidNumber
slapd debug  conn=2685 op=4531 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=13 nentries=0 text=TLS confidentiality required
slapd debug  conn=2685 op=4532 ABANDON msg=4532
slapd debug  conn=2671 op=4367 SRCH base="dc=example,dc=net" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)    (uid=ambari-qa))"
slapd debug  conn=2671 op=4367 SRCH attr=uid uidNumber
slapd debug  conn=2671 op=4367 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=13 nentries=0 text=TLS confidentiality required
slapd debug  conn=2419 op=4785 SRCH base="dc=example,dc=net" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=ambari-qa))"
slapd debug  conn=2419 op=4785 SRCH attr=uid uidNumber
slapd debug  conn=2419 op=4785 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=13 nentries=0 text=TLS confidentiality required
slapd debug  conn=2671 op=4368 ABANDON msg=4368
slapd debug  conn=2419 op=4786 ABANDON msg=4786
slapd debug  conn=2671 op=4369 SRCH base="dc=example,dc=net" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=ambari-qa))"
slapd debug  conn=2671 op=4369 SRCH attr=uid uidNumber
slapd debug  conn=2671 op=4369 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=13 nentries=0 text=TLS confidentiality required
slapd debug  conn=2671 op=4370 ABANDON msg=4370
slapd debug  conn=16627 fd=13 ACCEPT from IP=masternode:40376 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
slapd debug  conn=16627 fd=13 closed (connection lost)
```

If I do ambari-server sync-ldap --existing I get

```
Completed LDAP Sync.
Summary:
  memberships:
    removed = 0
    created = 0
  users:
    skipped = 0
    removed = 0
    updated = 0
    created = 0
  groups:
    updated = 0
    removed = 0
    created = 0
Ambari Server 'sync-ldap' completed successfully.
```

But the ldap server still gives the same error: err=13 nentries=0 text=TLS confidentiality required

```
slapd debug  conn=16682 fd=13 ACCEPT from IP=datanode2:42940 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
slapd debug  conn=16682 op=0 BIND dn="" method=128
slapd debug  conn=16682 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
slapd debug  conn=16682 op=1 SRCH base="dc=example,dc=net" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uidNumber=-1))"
slapd debug  conn=16682 op=1 SRCH attr=uid userPassword uidNumber gidNumber cn homeDirectory loginShell gecos description objectClass
slapd debug  conn=16682 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=13 nentries=0 text=TLS confidentiality required
slapd debug  conn=16682 op=2 UNBIND
slapd debug  conn=16682 fd=13 closed
```

The file /etc/ambari-server/conf/ambari.properties can read:

```
authentication.ldap.baseDn=dc=example,dc=net
authentication.ldap.bindAnonymously=false
authentication.ldap.dnAttribute=dn
authentication.ldap.groupMembershipAttr=gidNumber
authentication.ldap.groupNamingAttr=cn
authentication.ldap.groupObjectClass=posixGroup
authentication.ldap.managerDn=cn=admin,dc=example,dc=net
authentication.ldap.managerPassword=/etc/ambari-server/conf/ldap-password.dat
authentication.ldap.primaryUrl=host.example.net:389
authentication.ldap.referral=ignore
authentication.ldap.useSSL=true
authentication.ldap.userObjectClass=inetOrgPerson
authentication.ldap.usernameAttribute=uid
ldap.sync.username.collision.behavior=convert
ssl.trustStore.password=******
ssl.trustStore.path=/etc/ambari-server/keys/ldaps-keystore.jks
ssl.trustStore.type=jks
```

If I skip the self-signed certificate I then get this error when I do ambari-server sync-ldap --all:

```
ERROR [pool-18-thread-6] LdapSyncEventResourceProvider:460 - Caught exception running LDAP sync. 
org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 13 - TLS confidentiality required]; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 13 - TLS confidentiality required]
    at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:194)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.createContext(AbstractContextSource.java:356)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.doGetContext(AbstractContextSource.java:140)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.getReadOnlyContext(AbstractContextSource.java:159)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:357)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:309)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:642)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.security.ldap.AmbariLdapDataPopulator.getFilteredLdapUsers(AmbariLdapDataPopulator.java:667)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.security.ldap.AmbariLdapDataPopulator.getExternalLdapUserInfo(AmbariLdapDataPopulator.java:644)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.security.ldap.AmbariLdapDataPopulator.synchronizeAllLdapUsers(AmbariLdapDataPopulator.java:212)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariManagementControllerImpl.synchronizeLdapUsersAndGroups(AmbariManagementControllerImpl.java:5177)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.internal.LdapSyncEventResourceProvider.syncLdap(LdapSyncEventResourceProvider.java:490)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.internal.LdapSyncEventResourceProvider.processSyncEvents(LdapSyncEventResourceProvider.java:448)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.internal.LdapSyncEventResourceProvider.access$000(LdapSyncEventResourceProvider.java:65)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.internal.LdapSyncEventResourceProvider$1.run(LdapSyncEventResourceProvider.java:259)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.naming.AuthenticationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 13 - TLS confidentiality required]
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3127)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3082)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2883)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2797)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.<init>(LdapCtx.java:319)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURL(LdapCtxFactory.java:192)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getUsingURLs(LdapCtxFactory.java:210)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getLdapCtxInstance(LdapCtxFactory.java:153)
    at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory.getInitialContext(LdapCtxFactory.java:83)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
    at javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext.<init>(InitialLdapContext.java:154)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource.getDirContextInstance(LdapContextSource.java:42)
    at org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource.createContext(AbstractContextSource.java:344)
    ... 18 more
```

(ambari-server sync-ldap --existing yield the same result as in the other case).

The ldap server gives the same error: err=13 nentries=0 text=TLS confidentiality required

```
slapd debug  conn=16772 fd=13 ACCEPT from IP=masternode:41760 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
slapd debug  conn=16772 op=0 BIND dn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=net" method=128
slapd debug  conn=16772 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=13 text=TLS confidentiality required
slapd debug  conn=16772 fd=13 closed (connection lost)
slapd debug  conn=16773 fd=13 ACCEPT from IP=datanode1:35558 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
slapd debug  conn=16773 op=0 BIND dn="" method=128
slapd debug  conn=16773 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
slapd debug  conn=16773 op=1 SRCH base="dc=example,dc=net" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=root))"
slapd debug  conn=16773 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=13 nentries=0 text=TLS confidentiality required
slapd debug  conn=16773 op=2 UNBIND
slapd debug  conn=16773 fd=13 closed
```

I followed [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-encrypt-openldap-connections-using-starttls) to install the LDAP server and can use it from all the nodes. From what I understand a StartTLS connection requires the -Z option in the queries.

For example the query:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap:// -x -b "dc=example,dc=net" -LLL dn
```

will yield

```
Confidentiality required (13)
Additional information: TLS confidentiality required
```

While

```
ldapsearch -H ldap:// -x -b "dc=example,dc=com" -LLL -Z dn
```

Will work fine.

Unfortunately I have a very limited knowledge when it comes to LDAP. If I understand the problem I guess that Ambari is missing the -Z option when querying the LDAP. Is there a way to tell Ambari to add it when syncing with it ?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my issue come from that I had configured the LDAP to forces connection to use TLS:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcSecurity
olcSecurity: tls=1
```

I switched `olcSecurity: tls=1` to 0

The synchronization works fine now but I guess the connection between ambari-server and the LDAP is not encrypted anymore. I also noticed that the command `getent passwd` is now properly displaying the LDAP users while they were missing previously.